# $p>1$ and assume $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\leq 1-\frac{p}{n}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ large enough. Prove that $\sum_{n}a_n$ is convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let {$a_n$} and {$p_n$} be two sequences with $p_n>0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.
Let {$a_n$} be a positive sequence. Let $p>1$ and assume that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\leq 1-\frac{p}{n}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ large enough. Prove that $\sum_{n}a_n$ is convergent.

In this problem, hint is given: You may use the fact that $\sum_{n}\frac{1}{n^p}$ is convergent (for $p>1$).

My attempt was to use $\frac{a_n}{a_1}=\frac{a_2}{a_1} \cdots \frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}$ somehow, but I failed. Do I need to fix sufficiently large $n$ and then apply the given inequality? Because I'm not sure when I can use the hint, I'm confused.

Comment: Ah thank you Adam! I'll fix it!

Comment: That is [Raabe's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Raabe–Duhamel's_test)

Answer (score 0):

WLOG, we may assume $\{a_n\}$ is a decreasing sequence.

A proof can be as below:
$$\sum_{n=1}^N a_n=\sum_{n=1}^N (n+1)a_n-\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} (n+1)a_{n+1}$$

$$=(N+1)a_{N+1}-a_1+\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} (n+1)(a_n-a_{n+1})$$
$$=(N+1)a_{N+1}-a_1+\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} (n+1)(1-\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n})a_n$$

$$\ge (N+1)a_{N+1}-a_1+\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} (n+1)(\frac {p}{n})a_n$$

$$\implies a_1-(N+1)a_{N+1}\ge \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} (n+1)(\frac {p}{n})a_n-\sum_{n=1}^N a_n$$

$$\implies a_N+a_1-(N+1)a_{N+1}\ge \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} ((n+1)(\frac {p}{n})-1)a_n$$

$$\implies 2a_1\ge \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} (p-1)a_n,$$

which means $\sum a_n$ is convergent because $p\gt 1.$

---

**EDIT:** There are some proofs [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631348/proof-of-raabes-test) as well.