# Proof (check) of Raabe's test and help

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

**1.** If $(a_n)\neq0$ fo all $n$. If there is $\beta>1$ and $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|\leq1 -\frac{\beta}{n}$$ for all $n\ge N$. Then $\sum a_n$ is absolutely convergente.

**2.**
If  If $(a_n)\neq0$ fo all $n$. If there is $\beta\leq 1$ and $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|\geq1 -\frac{\beta}{n}$$ for all $n\ge N$. Then $\sum a_n$ is
**NOT** absolutely convergente. Additionally, if $a_n$ is positive for all $n$, then $\sum a_n$ diverges.

---

**Attempt**

**1.** Suppose, for a fixed number $\beta>1$, there is $N$ such that $a_n\neq0$ and $$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|\leq1 -\frac{\beta}{n}$$ for all $n\ge N$.

This is the same as $n|a_{n+1}|\leq n|a_n|-\beta|a_n|$ fo all $n\geq N$.

Then, $n|a_{n+1}|\leq n|a_n|+|a_n|-\beta|a_n| $. Thus, $(\beta -1)|a_n|\leq (n-1)|a_n|-n|a_{n+1}|$ for all $n\geq N$.

Since $\beta>1$, this yields $|a_n|< (n-1)|a_n|-n|a_{n+1}| $, then $0<|a_n|-|a_{n+1}|$. *I.e.*, the sequence is decreasing.
It follows that, $(|a_n|)$ is decreasing. Note that $|a_n|>0$, it is bounded. Therefore, the sequences  $(|a_n|)$ converges.

Now, define $x_n:=(n-1)|a_n|-n|a_{n+1}|$ for all $n\geq N$. Note that $\sum x_n$ is a telescoping series, so it converges.

Since $\beta-1>0$, then $|a_n|\leq\frac{x_n}{\beta-1}$. Now, applying the direct comparison test for convergent series $\sum a_n$ is abolutely convergent.

Is my attempt correct?

Now, I am stuck with point **2.**. Any help is more than welcome. Thanks!

Comment: For the second part, observe that $|a_3|\ge \frac{1}{2} |a_2|$,  $|a_4|\ge \frac{1}{3} |a_2|$, $|a_5|\ge \frac{1}{4} |a_2|$, ...

Comment: The first part is a duplicate. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4579580/p1-and-assume-fraca-n1a-n-leq-1-fracpn-for-all-n-in-mathbbn/4579652#4579652

Comment: @RezaRajaei Thanks for the comments. Could you please explain a little bit more your hint? I'm not quite sure I understood it, sorry.